# Django POST request always empty but it is not

Tags: django, django-views

I'm a noob  with Django.

I try to display the content of a POST request but I don't succeed. I'm using POSTMAN to produce POST request.

This is my view in Django :

```
@csrf_exempt
def prem(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        print("GET")
        context = {'contenu': request.GET.get("name") }
        # do_something()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        datar = request.POST.get('mykey','rien')
        context = { 'contenu' : datar }

    return render(request, 'polls/seco.html', context)
```

When I click on POST in POSTMAN, this is what my shell display :
[image]

So, my web app receive the POST request, but I cannot get its content.

```
This my template :
{% if contenu %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>{{ contenu }}</p>
    <p>Contenu detecté.</p>
{% endif %}
```

This is what POSTMAN display :
[image]

If someone could help me it would be really great ! :)

**EDIT**

Thank you guys for helping me. For noobs like me, below is the code now working :

```
def prem(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        print("GET")
        context = {'contenu': request.GET.get("name") }
        # do_something()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        datar = request.GET.get('mykey','rien') ### <------ HERE the mistake removed
        context = { 'contenu' : datar }

    return render(request, 'polls/seco.html', context)
```

Comment: These are the `request.GET` elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot .... I'm confused, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending a strange mixture of post and get here. The method is POST but you've sent the params in `request.GET`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm really confused, I mix in my head GET and POST .... Thanks for your help